# Generate variable name by merging another variable value (shell)

Tags: arrays, shell, variables

I have an array which contains

```
commName[0]="ls"
commName[1]="date"
commName[2]="crontab"
commName[3]="uname"
commName[4]="hostname"
```

Now the array doesn't always contain these. Sometimes it can have more indices sometimes less. And the values are not always `ls,date,...` They can be different. Bottom line, I don't know the size nor the values of the array when I'm coding.

Every array value `ls,date,...` has its own unique address. So for example, `ls` would have `/home/test/` and date would have `/home/test/test2/` etc... These addresses need to be stored into a variable which will be used later on in the code. So I should have following variables according to the given array

```
$lsAddress
$dateAddress
$crontabAddress
$unameAddress
$hostnameAddress
```

Therefore, I need a way to make these variables (have in mind that I don't know `ls,date,uname,....`)

My approach was this

```
for ((j=0 ; j<${#commName[@]} ; j++))
do
  set commName[$j]Nick="hi"
  echo $(${commName[$j]}Nick)
done
```

What I expected this to do was to create new variables for every index of the array and set them equal to `hi` (just for test purposes) and then access those new variables.

Also, The new created variables **Must** be accessible anywhere. So, I can't have a temporary variable that keeps getting replaced.

However, this method isn't working... Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: shouldn't it be `$i` instead of `$j` ??

Comment: @Anubhab yes you're right. Sorry I fixed it. However, that wasn't the issue. When I run that it tells me `lsNick: command not found`...`dateNick: command not found` etc...

Comment: yeah i knew that must be a typo.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval`. Try this:

```
for ((j=0 ; j<${#commName[@]} ; j++))
do
    param=`echo ${commName[$j]}Nick`
    eval "$param=hi1"
    eval "echo \$$param"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two parallel arrays, so that the entry in the command array matches with the corresponding entry in the address array.

```
commName[0]="ls"
commName[1]="date"
commName[2]="crontab"
commName[3]="uname"
commName[4]="hostname"

commAddress[0]="/home/test/"       # ls
commAddress[1]="/home/test/test2"  # date
# etc
```

Then, when you have a particular value of `i`, you know that `${commName[i]}` and `${commAddress[i]}` go together.

I recommend the two arrays, but you might also consider using `bash`'s indirect parameter expansion instead.

```
$ commName[0]="ls"
$ lsAddress="/home/test"
$ name="${commName[0]}Address"
$ echo "${!name}"
/home/test
```

Comment: This helped Thanks. Just Something. Since I will be having lots of `name` variable, I have to number them. as in `export name$j=$(echo "hello")` This works and stores hello into `name0,name1,etc...` However, How can I access them?? When i do `echo $name0` it works. But when I do `echo $name$j` it doesn't work....!!!!!

Comment: You use indirect expansion again: `fullName="$name$j"; echo "${!fullName}"`.

Comment: Ok Here's what I do. `export name$j=$(echo "hello")` then i do `fullname="$param$j"` then i do `echo "${!fullname}" But when I run it I get the name of my script `./test.sh` with few newlines...

Comment: Really, I don't recommend trying to build dynamic variable names like this. Use arrays, or edit your question with more of your real code to show *what* you are trying to do, not *how* you are trying to do it.

Comment: The real code is very complex and confusing. The reason why I don't want to do it like an array is because every variable must become an array. So `name0,name1,name2` will become arrays. So if I put THEM into arrays, then they cannot become another array

Comment: This is sounding like a program that should be written something other than shell.

Comment: It would be good if the `${!fullname}` worked. Anyways thanks for your help